# Vue transition：Why is there no transition animation when switching between nested child routes

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, css-animations, vue-router

When I switching between `/test/c` and `/test/d`, about to disappear component not in the DOM Tree, I guess is it something to do with them having a common parent component. I had expected like from `/a` to `/b` leave's component have leaving animation, how can I fixed this problem？

Here is demo: [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-shamir-kr9608?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: your codesandbox doesn't work at all (not for me anyway) so, it's actually not very useful

Comment: i fixed the demo,can you take a look?thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add a `key` to the parent `<router-view :key="$route.path">`

Comment: I found other solutions, but I think yours is better，thx